# How to make multiple selects with the value from the previous select

Tags: javascript

Kinda new here and new to javascript
So I am trying to make a chained select in javascript and I want to create different select from the value in the previous one, it seems easy to make two, but what about three selects or more?

Here's some of my code that I tried

```
function firstSelect(){
            var x = document.getElementById('firstSelect').value;
            switch(x){
                case 'Food':
                    localStorage.setItem('first','food');
                    add(food, 'secondSelect');
                    document.getElementById('secondSelect').setAttribute('onchange',  secondSelect());
                    //alert(x);
                    break;
//more code to be added
        }

//trying to add a second select?
function secondSelect(){
            var x = document.getElementById('secondSelect').value;
            var first = localStorage.getItem('first');
            if(first == 'food'){
                for(i=0, i<food.length; i++){
                    if( x == food[i].value ){
                        add(food[i].value, 'thirdSelect');
                    }
                }
            }//more code to be added but this is the gist of it

        }   

//function to populate each select added
function add(itemArray, name){
            if(document.getElementById(name)){
                var element = document.getElementById(name);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }
                var list = document.createElement('select');
                list.setAttribute('id', name);
                var length = itemArray.length
                var opt;
                for(i=0;i<length;i++){
                    opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.setAttribute('value', itemArray[i].value);
                    opt.text = itemArray[i].text;
                    list.appendChild(opt);
                }
                document.body.appendChild(list);

        }

//here's how my data looks like
var food = [
            {value: "meat", text: "Meat"},
            {value: "vege", text: "Vegetables"},
            {value: "fruit", text: "Fruits"}
        ];

        var meat = [
            {value: "beef", text: "Beef"},
            {value: "chicken", text: "Chicken"},
            {value: "pork", text: "Pork"}
        ];

        var vege = [
            {value: "broccoli", text: "Broccoli"},
            {value: "spinach", text: "Spinach"},
            {value: "carrort", text: "Carrots"}
        ];
```

Basically I make different functions for the different level of select I make, not sure if I should do it like that but... if food is the first choice and meat/vege will be shown as the second select accordingly, so am I going to make another function for my third select(beef?chicken?pork?)
I was thinking about putting up one function for creating multiple selects but I am not sure how to write it as an onchange function, it seems to me that each onchange function for different select should be different too...?
Is there an efficient way of doing this?
Please

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is just a map
// for selecting value for the child selector when the parent is changed.
// Parents value are the keys here 
// the data to be passed to the child according to the current value  of parent are stored in the array

// Map for first chain
const datamap_1 = {
    1: [{
            value: 10,
            text: 'ten'
        },
        {
            value: 12,
            text: 'twelve'
        }
    ],
    2: [{
            value: 20,
            text: 'twenty'
        },
        {
            value: 21,
            text: 'twelve'
        }
    ],
    3: [{
        value: 30,
        text: 'thirty'
    },
    {
        value: 31,
        text: 'thirty one'
    }
]
};

// Map for second chain chain
const datamap_2 = {
    10: [{
            value: 100,
            text: 'hundred'
        },
        {
            value: 101,
            text: 'hundred and one'
        }
    ],
    20: [{
            value: 200,
            text: 'two hundred'
        },
        {
            value: 201,
            text: 'two hundred and one'
        }
    ]
};

class ChainedSelect{
    constructor (parent, child, map){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.child = child;
        this.data_map = map;
        this._attach_events();
        this._init();
    }

    // Just for selecting the first value in parent selected by default and initlizing the child
    _init(){
        const val = this.parent.value;
        this._make_options(this.data_map[val]);
    }

    // All the event handling goes here
    _attach_events(){    
        this.parent.onchange = (function(_this){
            return function(){
                const val = this.value;
                _this._make_options(_this.data_map[val]);
            }
        })(this)
    }

    // helper function for creating options from a passed array
    _make_options(data){
        this.child.innerHTML = '';
        if (!data) return ;
        for(let i=0;i <  data.length;i++){
            let opt = data[i];
            let el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt.text;
            el.value = opt.value;
            this.child.appendChild(el);
            this.child.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
        }
    }


}

window.onload  = function(){
    const first = document.getElementById('first');
    const second = document.getElementById('second');
    const third = document.getElementById('third');
    const chain_1 = new ChainedSelect(first, second, datamap_1);
    const chain_2 = new ChainedSelect(second, third, datamap_2);

}
```

here is a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jgv8pd5k/